# Put analytics behind all links php

Tags: php, google-analytics

I am facing some problems by putting utm_source=&utm_campaign=&utm_medium= behind all links in my string.

My output is:
http://pastebin.com/WKb1sidu

And my full code so far is:

I have tried anything to make it working, but cannot fix the last thing. Is there any kind of better solution for this? Hmm, couldn't find anything on google and stackoverflow.

```
function AppendCampaignToString($string) {
$regex = '#(<a href=")([^"]*)("[^>]*?>)#i';
return preg_replace_callback($regex, '_appendCampaignToString', $string);
}

function _AppendCampaignToString($match) {

global $utm;


//Tjek om der allerede er utm bag på, for så skal den ikke lave samme nummer.

if ( strpos($match[2], "utm_medium") === false):

$url = $match[2];

$ParseURLString = parse_url($url);

print_r($ParseURLString);

if ( !isset($ParseURLString['query'])):
      $add="?";
else:
      $add="&";
endif;

if ( isset($ParseURLString['query']) && $ParseURLString['path'] == "/"):
      $add="?";
endif;

if ( !isset($ParseURLString['path']) && $ParseURLString['path'] == "/"):
     $slash= "";
endif;

if ( empty($ParseURLString['scheme']) || !isset($ParseURLString['scheme'])):
      $scheme = "http://" . str_replace("www.","",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
else:
      $scheme = $ParseURLString['scheme'] . "://";
endif;

if ( strpos($ParseURLString['path'], ".")):
  $add="?";
  $slash="";

endif;



if ( !isset($ParseURLString['query'])):
    $url = $scheme  . $ParseURLString['host'] . $ParseURLString['path'] . $slash . $add . $ParseURLString['query'] . $utm;
else:
    $url = $scheme . $ParseURLString['host'] . $ParseURLString['path'] . $slash .  $add . $ParseURLString['query'] . $add . $utm;
endif;

//$url = str_replace($url, $newURL, $url);

return $match[1] . $url . $match[3];
else:
    return $match[1] . $match[2] . $match[3];
endif; 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

based on your output from your link, looks like there's a problem with your logic and you are prefixing the campaign params with a `?` when it should be a `&`.

Now, I didn't really fine-tooth your logic to figure out exactly where you're going wrong, but it seems like maybe you are over-complicating things..

You should be able to skip that `parse_url` and rebuilding stuff and just do something simpler like this:

```
if (strpos($url,'utm_medium')===false) {
  $url = explode('?',$url,2);
  $url = $url[0] . '?' . $utm;
  if (isset($url[1])) $url .='&'.$url[1];
}
```